# a struct with a flexible array member in another struct

Tags: c, flexible-array-member

Is something like the code below valid?

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    int b[];
};

struct bar {
    int c;
    struct foo d;
};

struct bar *x = malloc(sizeof(struct bar) + sizeof(int [128]));
```

It seems ok to me, but I am a bit skeptical because compiler does not complain if I do:

```
struct bar {
    struct foo d;
    int c;
};
```

Comment: @Shahbaz: No, `int b[]` is *not* the same as `int *b`.  This construct is called a *flexible array member*. http://www.c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html

Comment: @jamesdlin, didn't know that! It seems like a terrible idea, though. How could they make it standard?

Comment: @Shahbaz It's not a terrible idea, it's just dangerous if people use it wrongly. It was a common hack to have arrays of length 1 as last members of `struct`s for that purpose before it became standard. gcc had long accepted 0-length arrays as flexible array members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not okay. Section 6.7.2.1 (in n1570), point 3 says

> 3 A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
>   a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
>   of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
>   may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
>   recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
>   element of an array.

So a `struct` with a flexible array member may not be part of another struct.

(It may well work as the last member of a struct, though, if the compiler accepts it.)